# AttributeError: 'SQLighter' object has no attribute 'connection'

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to write a bot for telegrams, so that if a person was subscribed to the mailing list, he received an article on StopGame. when I run the program everything is fine but when I write the bot the command /subscribe Gives an error : AttributeError: 'SQLighter' object has no attribute 'connection'
The database is called bd
My code:
bot.py

```
 import config
import logging
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from sqlighter import SQLighter

from stopgame import StopGame

# задаем уровень логов
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

# инициализируем бота
bot = Bot(token=config.API_TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# инициализируем соединение с БД
db = SQLighter('db.db')

# инициализируем парсер
sg = StopGame('lastkey.txt')

# Команда активации подписки
@dp.message_handler(commands=['subscribe'])
async def subscribe(message: types.Message):
    if(not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        # если юзера нет в базе, добавляем его
        db.add_subscriber(message.from_user.id)
    else:
        # если он уже есть, то просто обновляем ему статус подписки
        db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, True)

    await message.answer("Вы успешно подписались на рассылку!\nЖдите, скоро выйдут новые обзоры и вы узнаете о них первыми =)")

# Команда отписки
@dp.message_handler(commands=['unsubscribe'])
async def unsubscribe(message: types.Message):
    if(not db.subscriber_exists(message.from_user.id)):
        # если юзера нет в базе, добавляем его с неактивной подпиской (запоминаем)
        db.add_subscriber(message.from_user.id, False)
        await message.answer("Вы итак не подписаны.")
    else:
        # если он уже есть, то просто обновляем ему статус подписки
        db.update_subscription(message.from_user.id, False)
        await message.answer("Вы успешно отписаны от рассылки.")

# проверяем наличие новых игр и делаем рассылки
async def scheduled(wait_for):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(wait_for)

        # проверяем наличие новых игр
        new_games = sg.new_games()

        if(new_games):
            # если игры есть, переворачиваем список и итерируем
            new_games.reverse()
            for ng in new_games:
                # парсим инфу о новой игре
                nfo = sg.game_info(ng)

                # получаем список подписчиков бота
                subscriptions = db.get_subscriptions()

                # отправляем всем новость
                with open(sg.download_image(nfo['image']), 'rb') as photo:
                    for s in subscriptions:
                        await bot.send_photo(
                            s[1],
                            photo,
                            caption = nfo['title'] + "\n" + "Оценка: " + nfo['score'] + "\n" + nfo['excerpt'] + "\n\n" + nfo['link'],
                            disable_notification = True
                        )

                # обновляем ключ
                sg.update_lastkey(nfo['id'])

# запускаем лонг поллинг
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dp.loop.create_task(scheduled(10)) # пока что оставим 10 секунд (в качестве теста)
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

sqlighter.py

```
import sqlite3


class SQLighter:

    def __init__(self, database):
        """Подключаемся к БД и сохраняем курсор соединения"""
        con = sqlite3.connect('db.db')
        cur = con.cursor()

    def get_subscriptions(self, status = True):
        """Получаем всех активных подписчиков бота"""
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `subscriptions` WHERE `status` = ?", (status,)).fetchall()

    def subscriber_exists(self, user_id):
        """Проверяем, есть ли уже юзер в базе"""
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM `subscriptions` WHERE `user_id` = ?', (user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))

    def add_subscriber(self, user_id, status = True):
        """Добавляем нового подписчика"""
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO `subscriptions` (`user_id`, `status`) VALUES(?,?)", (user_id,status))

    def update_subscription(self, user_id, status):
        """Обновляем статус подписки пользователя"""
        with self.connection:
            return self.cursor.execute("UPDATE `subscriptions` SET `status` = ? WHERE `user_id` = ?", (status, user_id))

    def close(self):
        """Закрываем соединение с БД"""
        self.connection.close()
```

Comment: I think your "con" variable should be changed to "connection" and "cur" should be changed to "cursor" in the __init__ method

Comment: Still the same mistake